# How to access AWS Redshift

Tags: jdbc

Hello i am trying to access AWS redshift server. I have the driver installed

```
JDBC[
 "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver",...
]
```

However it seems that i can't initialize the interface
The driver works on my system, i verified it via accessing Redshift
using the SQLWorkbechJ

thank you very much in advance for any help you could offer, Bernd

Comment: Update: I was able to get the connection working using the latest redshift driver. Unfortunately there is now the following error message:  JDBC::error: [Amazon][JDSI](20280) Required setting ConnSchema is not present in connection settings.     I have been looking for information on how to provide the ConnSchema information, however could not find anything. Would anyone have any advise ?

Answer (score 4):

The error you're getting,

> Required setting ConnSchema is not present in connection settings

is telling you that you need to include the name of the database in the URL.  [Per the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html), make sure your URL looks like:

jdbc:redshift://endpoint:port/database

You're probably missing the /database part.

Also, make sure you have a JDK installed.

HTH!

Cheers,

-Maashu